# Simple jQuery Chained Dropdown Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following excerpt of code on my website (also available as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpvj0jv0/2/)). It's 2 select fields that show different data depending on selection.

I have **2 bugs**.

1) When I select `US` & then `Alaska`, the Alaska(`ak`) div does not display as I'd hope.

&

2) When I move from `Alaska` back to `Choose a state...` it displays everything again (United Kingdom & US), instead of resorting back to just the US(`us`) div. Help?

**CODE:**

```
<form method="get" action="/" id="languageSwitch">
        <fieldset>

            <select name='cat' id='cat' class='postform' >
                <option value='0' selected='selected'>Choose a country&#8230;</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="united-kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="us">US</option>
            </select>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery('#cat').change(function(){
                    jQuery('#cat').change(function() {
                      jQuery("#statecat").toggle(jQuery(this).val() == "us");
                    });

                    if(jQuery('#cat').val()=="0")
                    jQuery('form#languageSwitch').siblings('div').show();
                        else{
                        jQuery('form').siblings('div').hide();
                        jQuery('.'+jQuery('#cat').val()).show();

                        }
                    });
            </script> 

        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <form method="get" action="/" id="stateSwitch">
        <fieldset>

            <select name='statecat' id='statecat' class='postform' >
                <option value='0' selected='selected'>Choose a state&#8230;</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="ak">Alaska</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="wy">Wyoming</option>
            </select>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery('#statecat').change(function(){
                    if(jQuery('#statecat').val()=="0")
                    jQuery('form#stateSwitch').siblings('div').show();
                        else{
                        jQuery('form').siblings('div').hide();
                        jQuery('.'+jQuery('#statecat').val()).show();

                        }
                    });
            </script> 

        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div class="united-kingdom">
        <h2>United Kingdom</h2>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>

    <div class="us">
        <h2>US</h2>
        <div class="ak">
        <h2>Alaska</h2><ul>                  
            <li class="animal-listing" id="post-123">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/company/kiwi-kompany/">Alaska Test</a><br />
                Address:<br />Address<br />
                Country: Alaska<br />
                URL: http://www.somesite.co.nz<br />
                Telephone: 01902<br />
                Fax: 01293
            </li>

            <h2>Employees</h2>

            <span>Me</span><br /><span></span><br /><span>(012)020-0202</span><br /><span>email@site.com</span><br /><img alt='' src='' class='avatar avatar-128 photo' height='128' width='128' /></ul></div>

        <div class="as">
            <h2>American Samoa</h2>
            <ul></ul>
        </div>

        <div class="wy">
            <h2>Wyoming</h2>
            <ul></ul>
        </div>

        </ul></div>
```

Comment: You have lots of problems with this code - select option values not matching class names, jQuery selectors pointing to the wrong level of divs. Rather than list all the changes in an answer, I've updated your fiddle to get it closer to what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/Rhumborl/tpvj0jv0/3/. Bottom line, always check line-by-line when something isn't working, starting with the obvious things - everyone gets those wrong from time to time, however experienced they are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the first bug, I suggest you give a class (`state1`) to each state; this makes things easier.

You can then try this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#statecat').change(function(){
                $('.state1').each(function(){$(this).hide(); });
                if($('#statecat').val()=="ak")
                    $('.ak').show();
            });
        </script>

<div class="uk">
    <h2>United Kingdom</h2>
    <ul></ul>
</div>

<div class="us">
    <h2>US</h2>
    <div class="ak state1">
        <h2>Alaska</h2><ul>
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="as state1">
        <h2>American Samoa</h2>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>

    <div class="wy state1">
        <h2>Wyoming</h2>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>

 </div>
```

As Rhumborl pointed it, there are many problems in your code. Be careful to the fact that **HTML code with incorrectly nested and/or closed tags will very probably give you trouble**, even if they are displayed correctly in the browser.

For this reason, before writing any CSS and Javascript code, you should validate your HTML code in an HTML validator like: http://validator.nu/

Comment: Fantastic - that now works a treat! Both bugs fixed. However, I'm still puzzled why initially when I select `US`, the dropdown doesn't appear. Are you able to replicate that issue at your end?